# Ubuntu keeps saying could not open a connection to your authentication agent?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

And yes i did research this - the normal

```
eval `ssh-agent -s
```

is not working

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is my guess:

`man ssh-agent` states this:

```
ssh-agent is a program to hold private keys used for public
key authentication.  Through use of environment variables the
agent can be located and automatically used for authentication
when logging in to other machines using ssh(1)
```

So, your `eval $(ssh-agent -s)` command should correctly set the `SSH_AGENT_PID` and `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable in the invoking user environment ("indrajeet").

The problem, IMO, lies with invoking `ssh-add` with sudo, as root.  Root's environment will not contain those two variables.

You can try using the `-E` (preserve environment) option of the `sudo` command to pass your whole user environment variables to root:

`sudo -E ssh-add /root/.ssh/id_ed25519`

Or, better, use the `--preserve-env=...` option to pass only the revelant variables:

`sudo --preserve-env=SSH_AGENT_PID,SSH_AUTH_SOCK ssh-add /root/.ssh/id_ed25519`

Hope that helps.